# Unable to search and connect my headphones through Bluetooth

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, headphones

[settings[ZH-CN]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DxSA.png)

After executing the command 'sudo dmesg - T', there are errors related to Bluetooth ↓
[二 5月  9 22:44:16 2023] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)

I am trying to run a script from a github project:“ https://github.com/pedrovagner/fix-ubuntu-bluetooth-adapter
”, but this does not work.

How should I solve this problem to connect to my Bluetooth earphones?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I had problems with headphones, I had installed 'pulseaudio-module-bluetooth'.

Comment: Well, it has been already installed in system.......